# PhoneGap Build Facebook fql query doesn't return

Tags: cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk, phonegap-build

I'm using the phonegap facebook plugin (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin).

When I call make a fql query, it never returns. For example

```js
FB.api(
{
    method: 'fql.query',
    query: 'Select uid FROM user where uid=me()'
},
function(response) { alert("ok");}
);     (I don't get the alert)
```

However, when I make a regular api call, everything works fine. For example

```js
FB.api("/me",
   function(response) { alert("ok");}
); (alert executes successful )
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is the right way to make fql calls in cordova/phonegap

FB.api("fql", {q: query}, 
function(response) { alert("lalal");});

Got it from here: https://github.com/mgcrea/cordova-facebook-connect/issues/23